# Merge pandas doesn't work, it looks like concat

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I've been working with two dataframes (info_clients and metadata_clients) both have an **user_id** and **id_wp** column **as associated key**, respectively, and I loeaded info_clients into sql table and get the PK associated, then merge these dfs on user_id (by the left side) and id_wp (on the right).

info_clients: (72232, 1)

```
 user_id
0       0
1       1
2       4
3       5
4   39784
```

metadata_clients: (72232, 2)

```
        id  id_wp
0  1158426      0
1  1158427      1
2  1158428      4
3  1158429      5
4  1158430  39784
```

I used this:

```
merge = pd.merge( info_clients, metadata_clients, left_on=['user_id'], 
                            right_on=['id_wp'], how='left')
```

But it doesn't work as I expected, I had this result:

```
  user_id  cliente_fk  id_wp
0       0     1158426      0
1       1     1158427      1
2       4     1158428      4
3       5     1158429      5
4   39784     1158430  39784
Datamerge shape: (126680, 3)
```

When I save the info_clients data into sql table, I verify these data and I have *72232* clients saved.
I don't have nulls or nan values, I cleaned the data and checked its dtypes, both keys are int64.

Comment: if there are multiple values, for example, multiple `cliente_fk` for any `id_wp` you're going to get multiple rows in `merge`. you'll need to decide how you want to handle the "duplicates" if that's the case.

Comment: Can you confirm if you will have any duplicates?

Comment: No, I don't have duplicates, I removed in a previoust step, using: data.drop_duplicates( keep='first')

Comment: @DiegoTriana: that command doesn't do anything if the situation i mentioned is what is causing the duplicates because those are considered unique rows.

Answer (score 0):

You have a situation where you have duplicates:

> No, I don't have duplicates, I removed in a previoust step, using:
> `data.drop_duplicates(keep='first')`

I don't know if `data` is your first (`info_clients`) or your second (`metadata_clients`) but if you drop duplicates without set a subset of columns, it's likely you have no duplicate on entire row. You should try:

```
data = data.drop_duplicates('user_id', keep='first')

# OR

data = data.drop_duplicates('wp_id', keep='first')
```

You should try to debug with `value_counts`:

```
data.value_counts('user_id')

# OR

data.value_counts('wp_id')
```